# Hibernate @Embedded and @Embeddable

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I have to create a simple database using Hibernate, but whatever i did, i got this error:

org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: tr.com.ozer.datastructures.GameObject column: x (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")

Firstly i am using PostgreSQL 11, and Hibernate 5.4

Here is what i am trying to do:

```
@Embeddable
public class Position {

    private Integer x;

    private Integer y;

    // Setters end getters
}

@Entity
public class GameObject {
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @Embedded
    private Position absPosition;

    @Embedded
    private Position relativeToBaseA;

    @Embedded
    private Position relativeToBaseB;

    // Setters and getters
}
```

I do not want to use  @AttributeOverrride since my Position class have more fields then here and i dont want to define all of them for every field. Instead i would just write seperate fields.

And I dont care database column names so much atm. Are there any auto-naming mechanisim in Hibernate? Like absPosition_x, absPosition_y, relativeToBaseA_x, relativeToBaseA_y etc.

Note: Despite that i have the "implicit_naming_strategy" conf in my hibernate.cfg.xml, i still get the error. Here is the line:

```
<property name="hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy">org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyComponentPathImpl</property>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultComponentSafeNamingStrategy`?

Comment: Yes i tried all kinds of configurastions. And i have found the solution. It is my mistake that i have been using Hibernate 5 although i was using the old method when itinializing the service factory instance. After i have used StandardServiceRegistry, the error did not show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the error is on my part. But i will post my solution in case anyone has it.

I have been using Hibernate 5 and initializing it with the old method. 
After i initialized with StandardServiceRegistry, the error perished.
It is actually interesting, the old way initializing metod works normal without @Embedded annotations on version 5.4. It should give "wrong way initialition error" or something and i wouldnt have spend hours on this one!